# Android: Change or disconnect from specific Cell Tower

Tags: android, gsm, telephony

I know you can get the CellInfo from the active radio and the neighboors cell radios as well with TelephonyManager. But , is there a way to disconnect from a specific cell / force connection with a neighboor one?

The reason behind this  is that I want to make an app to prevent Stingrays from intercepting the user's communications. Detection is possible due to the Cell IDs databases availables on the internet and their locations, so you can check if you are connecting to a valid Cell. What would you do if you detect that your user is currently connecting to a fake cell ?